# Convertir string base64 en una imagen en android

Tags: android-studio

tengo el codigo string de una imagen a base64, el problema esque este codigo necesito pasarlo a imagen, he visto que las plataformas online lo convierten perfecto, pero en Android? como podriar insertar este codigo base64 y que se convierta en una imagen mostrandola en ImageView.

estaba utilizando esto pero no me funciono:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.buildDrawingCache();
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

El formato es: *image/tiff*

Answer (score 2):

A ver si esto puede ayudarte:

```
    String base64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAA...";
    String base64Image = base64String.split(",")[1];

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Referencias:

https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-44-how-to-convert-base64-string-to-bitmap-53f98d5e57af

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview

Ejemplo:
https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html